# How to pass an integer value as a access database query from visual basic 2012

Tags: vb.net

`qarr` is an array containing variables, and my database contains these values, but after executing, `dr` doesn't seem to have any value in it.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ind = ind + 1
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    dataFile = path + "\Questions.mdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    Dim str As String
    myConnection.Open()
    str = "SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE NO = '" & (qarr(ind)) & "'"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    MsgBox(str)
    While dr.Read()
        Label2.Text = dr("Question").ToString
    End While
    myConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL code looks like this: `SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE NO = '3'`. `'3'` is a string. Is the table column `NO` really a text column or is it a number?

If it is a number, remove quotes (`'`):

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE NO = 3
```

Or in VB

```
str = "SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE NO = " & qarr(ind)
```

But consider using command parameters. They are safer and will do the job of passing parameters formatted the right way automatically. If you intend to return only one value, you can use the `ExecuteScalar` method; it returns the first field of the first row in the result set returned by the query. The `Using` statement takes care of closing the connection and releasing resources automatically, even if an exception should occur or the `Using` block should be left by a `Return` or `Exit` statement.

```
Dim question As String
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(provider & dataFile)
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT Question FROM Table_1 WHERE NO = @1"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", qarr(ind))

    conn.Open()
    question = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
End Using
If question IsNot Nothing Then
    Label2.Text = question
End If
```

---

Also be aware of the fact that the current working directory can be changed and that `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` can return an unexpected directory. Better use `Application.StartupPath`, if the mdb is in the application folder.

Comment: You SQL code looks like this: SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE NO = '3'. '3' is a string. Is the table column NO really a text column or is it a number?

If it is a number, remove quotes ('):

SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE NO = 3
Or in VB

str = "SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE NO = " & qarr(ind)

i actually tried everything. even when the query is passed as SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE NO = 3, there is no value present in dr, but according to the query and available data, there should be.

Comment: In order to be able to answer this question it is really necessary to know the column type of `NO`. Guessing and trying different SQLs is not a good option. Also an example of what the table contains and an example of what `qarr(ind)` contains would be useful. It is also necessary to know the type of the values in `qarr`. By the way: `qarr` does not contain variables, but values. How have you declared `qarr`? How are you adding values to `qarr`?

Comment: qarr is of integer type.
it is normally having values 1 to 50.
the column type for NO is number.

Comment: If both are numeric then the quotes are wrong for sure. Waht does my example with `ExecuteScalar` do?

Comment: im not getting any output on that either. and i know the quotes are wrong but i just tried everything, but it doesnt seem to work with integers and thats my problem. the problem exists only with integers.

Comment: What do you mean by "only with integers"? Are there numbers that are not integers? Please give some examples of values in the `NO` column.

Comment: i didnt mean that. i tried with a different column where there are characters such as a,b,c,... and i formatted the code according to that and it works. 

qarr contains integers and the column NO contains the same. numbers from 1 to 50 specifically, no other values.

Comment: Then it should work, unless `NO` is a text column containing numbers. Then there is the possibility that leading zeroes or whitespaces are disturbing the comparison. What is the exact type of `NO` in the mdb?